# How calculate centered div's left side space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have centered div for my side. Now I want to calculate left side blank space. How to do it by jquery.

### My Markup

```
<main id="page_main" role="main">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</main>
```

### My Css

```
#page_main
{
    width:100%;
}
.content
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Now I want to calculate the screen's left side blank space. Can you help me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) which returns coordinates of element relative to **document**. It return Object with `top` and `left` properties. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/993/)

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
 var c = $(".content").offset().left;
  $('.content').text(c)
}).resize();
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad Vracar. It works. As a beginner, i have to learn more.